# Настройка MySQL на шаред хостинге и время ответа сервера

Tags: mysql, оптимизация

Здравствуйте!
Возможно ли уменьшить время ответа сервера на шаред хостинге? 
Для теста сделан  простой php скрипт который выбирает (select) данные из таблицы в 50 000 строк. На странице ничего не выводится, просто обращение к бд и оповещение что скрипт выполнен. Время ответа этой страницы ~350 мс. На другом шаред хостинге точно такой же скрипт, такая же база и таблица, время - ~80 мс.
Интересно то, что хостинг где время ответа большое - это самый дорогой шаред тариф, а тот хостинг где время ответа маленькое - стандартный недорогой шаред.
Я правильно понимаю что дело в скорости работы MySQL? Можно ли как то повысить скорость ответа и с чего начать? 
Спасибо за ответы!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Очевидно же, что у другого хостинг провайдера просто лучше аппаратное обеспечение или нагрузка на сервере от клиентов на ресурсы меньше. Может у него диски стоят SSD (которые имеют IOPS в разы превосходящий обычные жесткие диски) или процессоры помощнее, и памяти оперативной выдается больше под базу. Может еще конечно быть дело в грамотных настройках движка MySQL, но более очевидный вариант все-таки аппаратное обеспечение. Сама MySQL тут не причем, она работает на том что ей дают и разница даже в несколько версий (если это конечно не разница в 5 лет в базах) не даст ощутимого прироста производительности, как это может дать SSD.

Стандартными методами можно только попробовать изменить настройки базы данных (увеличить всякие буферы), но это врятли возможно на shared хостинге.

Хотите большей производительности арендуйте VPS или выделенный сервер. Там вы получите полную свободу действий в настройке.

Comment: Еще стоит добавить, что на shared-хостингах часто несколько аккаунтов делят один и тот же инстанс MySQL, обращаясь к своим базам данных и соседи просто могут создать довольно серьезную нагрузку. Поэтому +1 к VPS, shared-хостинг - это рулетка.